# Select until next dot followed by \s?

Tags: regex

I could use some help writing a regex. I have the following text:

```
DEFINE BROWSE BW_SC20SDAN
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _DISPLAY-FIELDS BW_SC20SDAN C-Win _FREEFORM
  QUERY BW_SC20SDAN NO-LOCK DISPLAY
      ZTYACC.prime    COLUMN-LABEL "" FORMAT "X(35)"
     ZUNACT.sec        COLUMN-LABEL "  " FORMAT "X(30)"
     INFDON.sep  COLUMN-LABEL "" FORMAT "99/99/9999"
     IF INFDON.top THEN  "S" ELSE (IF INFDON.REPORT  THEN "R" ELSE (IF INFDON.prime <> "" THEN INFDON.prime ELSE ""))  COLUMN-LABEL "R" FORMAT "X(1)"
/* _UIB-CODE-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME
    WITH SEPARATORS SIZE 83.57 BY 5.08
         BGCOLOR 15 FGCOLOR 1 FONT 6 FIT-LAST-COLUMN.
```

I have to find this whole block in a text file, so far I have this regex:

```
(?:DEFINE|DEF)\s([\w\s]*)BROWSE\s+([\w-]+)\s+([^.]*)\.
```

My problem is that it selects only this :

```
DEFINE BROWSE BW_SC20SDAN
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _DISPLAY-FIELDS BW_SC20SDAN C-Win _FREEFORM
  QUERY BW_SC20SDAN NO-LOCK DISPLAY
      ZTYACC.
```

When I want to select until the final point. Basically, the rule I want to apply is "until next dot followed by \s".

But I can't figure out how to write this regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow "non-dot" `[^.]` OR "dots not followed by space" `\.(?!\s)`:

```
DEF(INE)?\s([\w\s]*)BROWSE\s+([\w-]+)\s+(([^.]|\.(?!\s))*)\.
```

Note also the simplification of the leading term.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most readable way to do that is

```
(?:DEFINE|DEF)\s([\w\s]*)BROWSE[\S\s]+?\.\s
```

You turn the `+` operator lazy with ?, meaning by default it matches everything until it hits the first period followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use an ungreedy regex library, the simplest yet closest to what you specified would be

```
DEFINE\s+BROWSE.*?\.\s
```

Note, however, that the trailing whitespace may not be there at the end of your input text, leaving the last statement unmatched.

You may find it useful to have a lexer (scanner) like flex or ANTLR tokenize your string. This approach has the advantage that the lexer takes care of the white space and lets you specify the form of the block of interest in more detail.